# Calculate Daily Orders by Category in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I go about calculating average daily orders by an organization, by item in dplyr?

The end state is to feed into a re-order point calculation, where I would need to know the average daily orders an organization makes for a certain item.

I am trying to use summarize(), but I'm better at Python than R and I can't seem to wrap my head around how this would look like. This is where I'm at:

```
summary2<-all_orders %>% group_by(c("Storage Location","Material")) %>% summarize(daily_rate=???)
```

Other columns I would need are "Quantity" & "Purchase Order Date"

EDIT: Storage Location IS the identifier I use for Organization. I apologize for the lack of details. The dataset sample is below:

```
df<-structure(list(`Purchase Order Date` = structure(c(18256, 18220, 
18220, 18220, 18220, 18221), class = "Date"), `Requirement Priority` = c("12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12"), `Storage Location` = c("0I16", 
"0I16", "0I16", "0I16", "0I16", "0I16"), `Short Text` = c("SEAL,PLAIN ENCASED", 
"ACTUATOR,MECHANICAL,NONAIRCRAFT", "ACTUATOR,MECHANICAL,NONAIRCRAFT", 
"CLIP,ROD RETAINER", "CLIP,ROD RETAINER", "FLASHER,THERMAL"), 
    `Gross order value` = c(10.02, 135.7, 135.7, 0.84, 0.84, 
    32.69), Status = c("Closed", "Closed", "Closed", "Closed", 
    "Closed", "Closed"), `Order Quantity` = c(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), `Delivery Date` = structure(c(18257, 18221, 18221, 18221, 
    18221, 18222), class = "Date"), `Net Order Price` = c(3.34, 
    135.7, 135.7, 0.84, 0.84, 32.69), Material = c("012036551", 
    "013757322", "013757322", "015220393", "015220393", "007893706"
    ), lead_time = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please provide an example dataset, you can use `dput(head(all_orders))`

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided (a) a short reproducible sample of your data - `dput()` is the best way to share this, e.g., `dput(all_orders[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. This is copy/pasteable and includes structure and class info. (b) A bit of clarity in what you want...

Comment: E.g., you say *"average daily orders by an organization, by item"*, so I'd expect to see organization and item in your `group_by`, is that what `Storage Location` and `Material` are? And for calculating the daily rate, we may need to aggregate first at the day level, unless your data starts that way? And when you say *'Other columns I would need are "Quantity" & "Purchase Order Date'*, can you be specific about that? It would help a lot if you show your desired output corresponding to your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

all_orders %>% 
  group_by(`Storage Location`, Material) %>%
  # total quantity divided by number of unique dates
  summarise(daily_rate = sum(`Order Quantity`) / n_distinct(`Purchase Order Date`))
```